# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} - 3$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} - 3$ for every natural $n$.

I've already tried to write it like this:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{1} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} + ... + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} - 3$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} + ... + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} - 4$$
but I don't know that to do next or if it's the right way prove this.

Comment: Have you tried comparing it to $\int_1^n\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: Mathematical induction is likely to be a good approach.

Comment: Can you prove that for all $n\ge1$ we have
$$3\sqrt n+\frac1{\sqrt n}\le 3\sqrt{n+1}?$$ In other words, I agree with Dylan.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I also had in mind induction but I don't know why at first I kept the $-3$ term! Eliminating it it is really straightforward.

Comment: @user, to tell you the truth I first plotted the difference between the two sides of that inductive step with Mathematica. To be sure that it holds! And with the $-3$ on both sides :-). Only then I started removing the clutter, including using $n$ in place of $n+1$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yes, indeed, a stupid mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction we have

- base case: $n=1 \implies 1 \le 3\sqrt 2-3$
- inductive step: we assume true

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + … + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} - 3 \tag 1$$

and we need to prove that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + … + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \stackrel{(1)}\leq 3\sqrt{n+1} - 3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \stackrel{?}\le 3\sqrt{n+2} - 3$$

and last inequality is true indeed

$$ 3\sqrt{n+1} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\le 3\sqrt{n+2} $$

$$ 3(n+1) +1\le 3\sqrt{(n+2)(n+1)} $$

$$ 3n+4\le 3\sqrt{(n+2)(n+1)} $$

$$ 9n^2+24n+16\le 9n^2+27n+18 $$

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using induction?

Let's assume the following proposition is true for $n$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} -3$$

By induction we must prove it works for the case $n=1$ and for all the cases $n+1$.

$P(1)$:

The base case is trivial, since
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} = 1 \leq 3\sqrt{2} -3 = 3(\sqrt2 - 1)$$

Since $\sqrt2 > 1$ it is easy to see why it is true.

Now we must bring our proposition $p(n) := \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} -3$ to test for all $n+1$ and see if it holds.

$P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} -3$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}) \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} -3 + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+1} -3 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+2} - 3 $$

Therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+2} - 3 $$

You can check that $3\sqrt{n+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leq 3\sqrt{n+2}$ is true for all $n$. Hence we proved by induction that the inequality $P(n)$ is true.

Comment: There is a typo for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\color{red}k}} $.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you!